# Open source project to retrieve media and meta data from URL

Tags: youtube, metadata, web-scraping

My question title might not be clear enough.

When you use Facebook to post a link to a Youtube video, they automagically show the embedded player on your wall. Same if you post links to different media sites, or sometimes it shows a thumbnail for an article you post, etc ...

I would like to recreate a similar feature on my site. Is there some open source code I can use, do I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wanna take a look at this: http://protonet.info/post/1005627617/art-of-turning-urls-into-user-readable-previews